# RxJava на поток подписываются сразу несколько подписчиков

Tags: android, rxjava

Использую RxJava2. На поток подписываются сразу несколько подписчиков (от 2 до N), из-за чего получение данных происходит столько раз, сколько существует подписчиков.

Главный класс (NewsPresenter)

```
private var view: INews.View? = null
private var viewAdapter: INewsAdapter.View? = null
private var modelAdapter: INewsAdapter.Model? = null

private val model = Model()
private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

private var count = 0
private var offset = false
private var last_id = -1

private var isInitScrollTh = false

override fun unbind() {
    view = null
    viewAdapter = null
    modelAdapter = null
}

override fun bind(view: INews.View, viewAdapter: INewsAdapter.View, modelAdapter: INewsAdapter.Model) {
    this.view = view
    this.viewAdapter = viewAdapter
    this.modelAdapter = modelAdapter

    getNews(true)
}

private fun getNews(clear: Boolean) {

    if (clear) {
        count = 0
        offset = false
        last_id = -1
    }

    if (last_id != 0) {

        view?.showProgress()

        val getter = GetterNews(offset, last_id)
        val request = ServerRequest(operation = Constants.OPERATION_GET_NEWS, getterNews = getter)
        val th = model.network(request)

        if (th != null) {
            val list = ArrayList<News>()

            val disp_getNews = th
                    .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .doOnTerminate {
                        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "2")
                        terminateGetNews(list)
                    }
                    .subscribe { it ->
                        if (it.result == Constants.SUCCESS) {
                            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "1")
                            list.addAll(it.news)
                            count++
                            it.getterNews.last_id?.let { last_id = if (last_id != it) it else 0 }
                        } else {
                            view?.showSnackbar(HelpMethods.responseError(it))
                        }
                    }

            disposables.add(disp_getNews)
        }
    }
}

private fun terminateGetNews(list: ArrayList<News>) {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "d: -> " + disposables.size().toString())

    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        if (!offset) {
            view?.hideRv()
        }
    } else {
        if (!offset) {
            modelAdapter?.setNews(list)
            modelAdapter?.notifyAdapter()
            view?.showRv()
            offset = true
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "set")
        } else {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "add")
            modelAdapter?.addNews(list)
            modelAdapter?.notifySomeItems(count * 10)
        }

        if (!isInitScrollTh) {
            val disp_scroll = initScrollEvent()
            disposables.add(disp_scroll)
            isInitScrollTh = true
        }
    }

    view?.hideProgress()

}

override fun refresh() {
    getNews(true)
}


override fun clearTh() {
    disposables.clear()
    disposables.dispose()
}

private fun initScrollEvent(): Disposable {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "th")
    return getScrollObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "s")
                getNews(false)
            })
}

private fun getScrollObservable(): Observable<Unit> =
        Observable.create<Unit>({ subscriber ->
            val listener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    if (!subscriber.isDisposed) {
                        val offset = 10 * (count - 1)
                        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                        val position = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                        val updatePosition = offset + 8


                        /*  Log.i(Constants.TAG, position.toString())
                          Log.i(Constants.TAG, updatePosition.toString())*/

                        if (position >= updatePosition) {
                            // Log.i(Constants.TAG, "update")
                            subscriber.onNext(Unit)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            view?.recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(listener)
            subscriber.setCancellable {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ca")
                view?.recyclerView?.removeOnScrollListener(listener) }
            if (view?.recyclerView?.adapter?.itemCount == 0)
                subscriber.onNext(Unit)
        })
```

Class Model

```
fun network(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Observable<ServerResponse>? =
        api?.post(serverRequest)
                ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                ?.filter { it -> it != null }
                ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По коду ничего не понял, но надеюсь подтолкну к решению проблемы - путей решения несколько:

1 - Отписывать тех обсерверов которые уже не нужны. Добавляете их в отдельный `CompositeDisposable` и когда их надо отписать, вызываете `dispose()` или `clear()`

2 - `Observable` приводите к `Single`. Зачем? `Observable` работает, пока у него есть подписчик или пока не вызовут `onComplete()`, который в вашем случае, я так понял, не вызывается. `Single` же это тот же `Observable` но который отработает всего один раз. Возможно вам так же пригодится `Completable`. Он тоже отрабатывает всего один раз, но не возвращает результата.